# Max File size and Connections supported by SQL CE 4.0 and SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, sql-server-ce

what is the max File/DB size and Connections supported by SQL CE 4.0 and SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server Compact 4.0: Max size 4 GB and 256 connections (from same OS instance)

Comment: With this Connection string: ("Data Source=C:\\Test.sdf;Max Database Size=4091"); --- 4GB and With this Connection string: ("Data Source=C:\\Test.sdf;); --- 256MB